# How to allow user to set a profile attribute when signing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My Profile model has a full_name attribute, but I want it to be set when the user signs up by the User create method. The profile and user are two separate models with two separate controllers. Can I do this? If so, how?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have full_name on User? Then each Profile will have a User and the Profile can just delegate the `full_name` accessor to its User; or the view could just use `profile.user.full_name` instead of `profile.full_name`.

Comment: yeah true... probably would make things much easier...

Comment: why is the profile a different model from the user? wouldn't all the profile attributes be for the user?

Comment: @corroded I actually asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365834/profile-model-association-question and I decided to go with two separate models...

Comment: the thing is that I'd like User to only be comprised of the login essentials, while the profile consist of the public information, but if moving the name to the User model is the only way to have it set upon signup, then I'll do that.

Comment: @corroded: I can see reasons for separating the profile model and the user model; for example, the profile may contain a lot of extra data that you don't want to load just to sign someone in or do an access check. However, that separation should be hidden by the user interface (i.e. user contains a profile and exposes all of the profile models through delegation with lazy-loading of the profile object).

Comment: @Justin: The full_name would be better off on User, that's part of the user's identity so it makes sense; the full name will also only be a short string so pulling it out of the database will be cheap compared to the database access overhead.

Comment: @mu is too short, ok that's what I'll do. If you write an answer i'll accept it :)

Comment: by the way, if I want a user to be able to edit the name from the profile, would that be possible?

Comment: oh i see. if that's the case i agree with mu on this one. also, editing the name from the profile should be possible using a simple params get and updating the user in the controller(or you could make that a separate form with all the other editable fields from the user)

Comment: If you hide the profile inside the user then you'd be editing the user and the user object would pass profile changes to the contained profile. Look up "delegation" and "composite design pattern" to help clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense to have full_name on User? Then each Profile will have a User and the Profile can just delegate the full_name accessor to its User; or the view could just use `profile.user.full_name` instead of `profile.full_name`.

Comment: thanks mu, could you also post an example of what I would need to put in my view and/or controller so that I can update the name from the profile edit view?

Comment: @Justin: You got that all sorted out in another question, right?

Comment: yep I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447651/how-to-edit-a-models-attribute-from-the-view-of-another-associated-model  Thanks for the help!