# How to edit a model's attribute from the view of another associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have a user model which has_one profile. The user model has a name attribute which is set when a user signs up. However, I want to let a user update that name attribute from the profile's edit view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested attributes and the [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) form helper are your friends.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

That allows you to give nested user attributes to the profile:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > params = { :profile => { :some_profile_attr => "some value", :user_attributes => { :name => "some_new_name" }}}
 => true
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > profile.update_attributes params[:profile]
 => true
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > profile.user.name
 => "some_new_name"
```

When you want to update the user attributes through the profile form you can use the fields_for form helper:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |profile_form| %>
  [..]
  <%= profile_form.fields_for :user do |user_form| %>
    <%= user_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  [..]
<% end %>
```

Comment: why'd you give an example with the user form? I want to edit a user attribute in the profile form. I guess what I want to do is your example except switching the user and profile around...

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. Had no coffee yet :-) I changed it.